# High CPU usage with multi-threaded HTTP requests with HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java, multithreading, httpurlconnection

I'm doing multi-threaded HTTP requests with a small Java library called Scribe. Scribe uses `HTTPUrlConnection` to make a request and reads the resulting `InputStream` to a String. The buffer size is 65kb, though the response size is typically 2MB, but I doubt that's a contributing factor.

When running 10 threads each doing HTTP requests my CPU usage is maxed out on all 4 cores. From profiling I can see that about 60% of CPU is spent calling `HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();` (presumably waiting for a response) and about 20% of my time is spent calling `InputStream.read()` in [StreamUtils](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/utils/StreamUtils.java).

In jVisualVM I can see that the threads are "running" the whole time. I figured that the underlying class would have a way of blocking the thread when doing I/O to free up CPU resources, but I guess my understanding is a little shaky here.

What is a more efficient way to perform parallel HTTP requests?

Comment: i havent used scribe but can you post some part of your implementation? that would be helpful..

Comment: Mine also spends time on `.getOutputStream()`. About equal CPU time than `getResponseCode()`.

Comment: I don't think this can be helped: the majority of time in `.getResponseCode()` is spent in parsing response headers, so it's not like WAITING for a response is taking CPU - it's processing the response content.

Comment: Err, don't use Scribe? Hard to see how any library can waste CPU cycles performing network-bound operations, which both `getOutputStream()` and `getResponseCode()` are, but if it's doing that, remove it. `HttpURLConnection` is easy enough to use directly.